# Bi-directional Map in Riak

Tags: dictionary, riak, bidirectional, bidirectional-relation

I want to store a structure similar to bi-directional map in Riak. I have two buckets with inversed keys and values.
I want to remove the record in the second bucket when it was removed from the first. As I understand, it can't be done with the hooks. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for seems to be referential integrity constraints, which Riak does not support. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, I know it and I try to emulate. I need a distributed, scalable, extremely fast big data system key-value store that will allow me to run queries as by key and by value.